# Error Starting MyApplication: Can't find entry point

Tags: blackberry

I was successfully created a signed Blackberry app. I have ever deployed it and succeed. But i wonder why somehow, when now i debug it, the app won't run and said,

```
Error Starting `MyApplication`: Can't find entry point
```

During debugging, my project doesn't show any errors, packaging works well. As far as i remember, i do not perform any significant changes on my code nor on the project description and properties, before i got this error.  Anyone here ever faced the same problem?

For your info, my project has only one main method and uses SMS listener thread inside `UiApplication` class. I get this error both on real device and simulator. I was trying to completely uninstall the app, but coincidentally it cannot be deleted because delete menu doesn't appear.

Comment: Could you post the main method declaration?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that the **main method is in a publicly accessible** Class, and add a breakpoint to the first line inside the method, to **check that the application isn't throwing an exception** and dying on your. Also try putting the whole main method into a try/catch with exception logging to get a look at what might/might not be going on.

Secondly, it is possible that the device/simulator being used just needs the previous version of the application deleting. Go to the settings and navigate to the third party installed apps, and make sure yours is removed. A reboot is required (battery pull). On simulator, navigate to the bin/simulator folder in your SDK directory and **run the cleanup.bat file to reset the simulator**. Then try again. You say that the delete menu doesn't appear, I assume this is on the Third party Installs screen?

A third option is to go into your **application descriptor xml** file, and check that there is a visible entry point, and that everything is correctly filled in.

Also try doing a **refresh and clean build**, and checking that all the files are correctly compiling (is there a class file created correctly in your bin folder? And has the distribution folder correctly populated with the cod/jad files for distribution?)

Another option is to **re-import the project into your IDE** to force the IDE to regenerate some files, and to try loading another project onto the device. If that works an option could be to copy your class files etc over to the new project.

Some of the above are a hassle, but welcome to BlackBerry development!